# Div appearing with hover

Tags: jquery, html

I have a question, currently I am working on a DIV that moves upwards when you hover on it.
I found a JS Fiddle on StackOverflow with the solution.(http://jsfiddle.net/N9uwD/19/)

Now I changed the `DIV` with my own needs, but suddenly the bottom of the `DIV` shakes, when it expands.(see http://jsfiddle.net/MeBxJ/609/)

I have trouble finding the solution of this problem. Can someone help me with finding the solution that the bottom won't shake when it expands? The css is now exactly how I need it (with top position etc).

http://jsfiddle.net/MeBxJ/609/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always get this if you are animating two things at once. To get this to work without the shake I would align the item to the bottom and just animate the height. I don't know how you intent to use this but it may be an option.

Comment: I changed the JS Fiddle now. I did it because this div is inside another one. Here is how it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/MeBxJ/642/ . you can see that the div is shaking on the bottom.

Comment: Try this instead. http://jsfiddle.net/89HPn/1/ Do you see how the holding DIV is position relative and the child DIV is position absolute, set the bottom:0;
Then I just animate the height - it grows from the bottom up!

Comment: Is it btw possible to stop the animation when leaving the div? Now if I spam hover with my mouse it keeps going up and down. Do you know that?

Comment: Sure. You need to check out the jQuery stop() method. It stops all animations on your selected elements. If you pass through "true" it also clears the queue, if you pass through "true,true" if clears the queue and makes the animation jump to the end.
I've added it so you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/89HPn/2/
Ps if this has helped can you please mark this as the answer? I'm new to stackoverflow :D

Answer (score 2):

Done ! The solution was to insert a bottom attribute so that the bottom of the div always remains constant. Then you need to just animate the height.

Since you were changing the top and height simultaneously, the bottom was shaking.

http://jsfiddle.net/MeBxJ/644/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are setting the height to `69px` not `70px`. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/MeBxJ/613/) how you intended?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you have set `top` in the css.

With `top` not set in css and `top` in the JavaScript set to go from `0px` to `-35px` and `<br>`s to bring it down to where you wanted it, it seems to work without the bottom jiggling.

http://jsfiddle.net/MeBxJ/633/